Titanic martyrs
The Strausses were a Jewish couple who died on the Titanic. The following story found in Wikipedia relates how they died:

On the night of the sinking, Isidor and Ida were seen standing near Lifeboat No. 8 in the company of Ida's maid, Ellen Bird. Although the officer in charge was willing to allow Isidor to board the lifeboat with the women, Isidor Straus refused to do so while women and children still remained on the ship. He urged Ida to board, but she refused, saying, "We have lived together for many years. Where you go, I go." This incident was witnessed by numerous witnesses both in the lifeboat and on deck. The Strauses were last seen standing arm in arm on the deck.
The story of Ida's bravery and loyalty became much celebrated. Rabbis spoke to their congregations about her sacrifice; articles in Yiddish- and German-language newspapers extolled her courage; a popular song featuring the story, "The Titanic's Disaster", became popular among Jewish Americans.

My question is whether their bravery aligns with Jewish law?
What should one do in this type of situation ל"ע

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/114019/are-you-allowed-to-risk-dying-to-save-others

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/sacrificing-ones-life-for-anothers

https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4372124/jewish/The-Trolley-Problem-in-Judaism.htm#Volunteering
